# What does mean the colon with equal sign ":="

Tags: excel, vba, colon-equals

If foud this code:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(-5, -1).Range("A1:E1").Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Range( _
        "A1:E1")
```

I can't find any reference about ":=". What does it mean?

Comment: Normally I see := in pascal, which means becomes equal - sure thats from vba not delphi/pascal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:=` is used with named arguments.  In this case,  `Destination` is the name of an argument to the `Cut` method, and the other side is its value.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-named-arguments-and-optional-arguments for an example.