# What is colon ":=" marks definition and usage in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

**Explain:**
I edited this question.
**Please remove my Negative votes, and offering positive ones, If possible.

StackOwerflow was banned me from asking questions.**

Help...

I was answered about whole ":" sign comment and sign its consist of ":=". But as a result of some guidance, I realized my question is wrong and those are two different signs.
Thus I changed and corrected my question.

---

### Question

In VBA for MS-Word, what is definition and usage of colon_equal ":=" mark?

Is it an operator?

Comment: Your comment is false. sorry. Please follow my bellow comment. Thanks.

Comment: If @JohnColeman has misinterpreted your question, you may need to make the question more specific by mentioning that you are only interested in what does `:=` mean.

Comment: Thanks. That's (" [What does mean the colon with equal sign ":=" – YowE3K](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972637/what-does-mean-the-colon-with-equal-sign)") my answer. But that reference is incomplete! and I ask about hole ":" operator, such as its rule in ":=". thanks

Comment: What do you mean the reference is incomplete?  And what do you mean by the "hole (whole?) ":" operator"?  `:=` is one thing, `:` is another thing - which one are you talking about?

Comment: My original comment is gone. `:` used as a separator and `:=` used in function calls are different tokens, not usefully thought of as special cases of the "whole `:`", just like `in` used in iterator-based loops and `integer` are different tokens with radically different meanings and are not usefully thought of as special cases of the "whole `in`" just because those two tokens begin with the same symbols. In any event, either interpretation of your question is a duplicate and the disjunction of two duplicates is still a duplicate.

Comment: Very thanks for this comment. Exactly. My question is about ":=", and that is not duplicated question. Because of above preferred reference is not a meaningful. Are there any resource about ":=" operator. Actually I ask ":=" and  [this Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972637/what-does-mean-the-colon-with-equal-sign) is incomplete.

Comment: I don't understand how you think that the other reference is either not meaningful or incomplete. `:=` has just 1 meaning in VBA, and not a very complicated meaning, and the accepted answer to that question says what that meaning is. It assigns values to named arguments in function or sub calls. Why do you say it is incomplete? What is it missing?

Comment: I apologize.  I searched about "Named argument" and read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251503.aspx). Thus I understand meaning of ":=". Thanks.

Comment: Help. "Stackoverflow" banned me from asking questions, because of this negative votes. Please say me why this question had collected 2 negative vote? Please help me to get out of question ban.

Comment: Just gave your question an upvote to get you back in the game. Two downvotes where a bit harsh maybe for a newcomer, I think. I hope this helps ...

Comment: Use full question.

Comment: That bothers me. Have an upvote! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A colon ":" imitates moving to a new line. For example you could write

```
Call MyMacro: Call MyMacro2
```

Instead of

```
Call MyMacro
Call MyMacro2
```

I wouldn't recommend writing in the style above, but it's useful for the Immediate Window where you can write

```
for each ws in worksheets: debug.Print ws.name: next ws
```

To answer your question in the comments, := allows you to specify a named argument. The benefits are that it's easier to read since you can see what each value relates to without Intellisense, but it's also better for optional arguments, so you can write

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ReadOnlyRecommended:=True
```

Instead of

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs , , , , True
```

Comment: Please say about when comma comes with "=" sign. In fact my need is about ":=" operator.

Comment: ":=" is to specify a named argument. I've explained above

Comment: I understand [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251503.aspx)

Comment: Help. "Stackoverflow" banned me from asking questions, because of this negative votes. Please say me why this question had collected 2 negative vote? Please help me to get out of question ban.

Answer (score 2):

It enables you to write several commands (=statements) on one line, see here:

http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/Lesson04.htm

Comment: Thanks, but what about when comma write with "=" sign. Means ":=". ":=" is an operator and whats that definition and description too? Example: `"Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend"`

Comment: Your answer Of course right but not enough. Please note ":=" form of using ":" sign. Please say more about ":=" operator and exact usage of that.

Comment: I Understand.  [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251503.aspx)

Comment: Help. "Stackoverflow" banned me from asking questions, because of this negative votes. Please say me why this question had collected 2 negative vote? Please help me to get out of question ban.